# Javascript function as class parameter?

Tags: javascript, class

I want a parameter of one of my classes to be a function that will be particular to an instance of that class.
In this case I have a sprite class, I want different "onCollide" functions to be called for different instances of this class. Here is what I have coded.

```
function StaticSprite(tileset, x, y, onCollide) {
    this.tileset = tileset;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.onCollide = onCollide;
}

var introSign = new StaticSprite(mainTiles, 800, 600, showMessage('Hi.'));

if (isColliding(player, introSign)) {
    introSign.onCollide();
}
```

This code obviously doesn't work but should at least show what I'm trying to achieve.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to *pass* it a function, not *execute* a function and pass the result:

```
new StaticSprite(..., function () { showMessage('Hi.'); })
```